# C#)How can I schedule Quartz job to run at 5 minutes from now?

Tags: c#, scheduler

I am trying to schedule a Quartz job to run at 5 minutes from now. I created a trigger with StartAt() function:

```
StartAt(DateTime().Now.Addminutes(5.0))
```

This doesn't seem to work and I couldn't find a reference for job scheduling without Cron Expression.

Is there a way to schedule a job with DateTime in C# ?

Comment: shouldn't it be this? `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5.0)`

Comment: Why not use the Windows Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Use Interval to set when it has to run.

```
  var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("trigger")
                    .ForJob("job")
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                        .WithIntervalInMinutes(5)
                        .RepeatForever())
                    .Build();
```